# In CQRS, how do you generate a correct autonumbered ID?

Tags: architecture, cqrs

So I've been reading up a little bit on CQRS lately and I was wondering how one would generate the correct auto numbered identifier for a command.  If the indentifer is a guid, you can just do Guid.NewGuid() to generate the identity, but how would you be able to generate a safe unique new number in an auto numbered int table?  My first thought is that you could select max on the table you are writing to, but what happens if two users are attempting a write at the same time and both think they have the next safe ID? Do you let the first in the queue write and reject the second+ write request and implement a retry pattern when you go to check the write status?  Let's assume that reconsidering database design is not an option.

Comment: can't you just relay on DB to pick next ID from sequence/auto_increment?

Comment: What would be the added value of doing it yourself instead of letting the database handle it?

Comment: If you let the database do it automatically, then you don't have an ID to use to check the status of the write operation.

Comment: not related to CQRS that much.

Comment: What other pattern requires you to generate an ID and send it in on your writes so that your command is write only?

Comment: @Hunter Nelson I guess my question was more like: what would be the advantage of using CQRS principles in this case, as compared to the traditional approach? Why should a command be write-only, why would you not want to return an ID, for example. It's obviously becoming more complex, is it worth it?

Comment: Advantages of using CQRS in certain situations are well documented. The question isn't is using CQRS worth it? The question is meant to help out people that have already committed to using or are considering using CQRS and have concerns about using auto numbered integers on insert and their compatibility with the pattern.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this post which describes a method where you can allocate blocks of unused ids and used allocated ids to supply as an identifier.  There are pros and cons to the approach.

http://enterprisecraftsmanship.com/2014/11/15/cqs-with-database-generated-ids/

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to let the database assign the next ID, you'll have to do it somewhere in the domain model.  In the domain model, constraints are protected by aggregates. In your case, unique numbering is a constraint, so you'll have to use an aggregate to generate a unique ID.

By the way, I have never encountered the need to generate a unique ID for a command.  Commands represent use-cases from the business perspective.  If you require commands to have a unique, sequential, gap-less ID, infrastructure requirements are leaking into your domain, which is clear code smell indicating bad design decisions.

Comment: I'm working on a 15 year old app that has some places in which a CQRS pattern makes sense.  However this app is riddled with auto number primary keys on most of the tables.  So, any modules that implemented a CQRS pattern would have to be compatible with the existing database structure.  I have the freedom to build modules with CQRS pattern, but not the freedom to influence certain aspects of design. It's sounding like unless I want/am able to use a natural key, I'm out of luck without being able to influence overall design as well..